# Microsoft Terminal Server clipboard corruption

Tags: terminal-server, copy, mstsc

I've got a client running Terminal Server 2008 R2, connecting from Windows XP terminal services client (not sure of the local RDP version, I think they've got all their service packs though) and whenever they copy text from the terminal server and paste it back on their machine, all they get is 5 Squares (regardless of what they copy or where they copy it from).

I'm debugging this for an application I am responsible for, but I get the same problem from Notepad as I do for my program, so I think it's a server problem (still my problem, eh?).

The option to use clipboard resources is checked.

Comment: If you check the optional updates section for XP in windows update, there is an updated client for terminal services. May be worth ensuring this has been updated on one or two client pc's and seeing if this helps.

Comment: What kind of content are you trying to copy?

Comment: Just plain text

Answer (score 2):

Double check the updates as suggest by Robin, also ensure you are running Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 on the XP machines (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20609). There are some major improvements, you can see this [KB for details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem.

You have 2 solutions:

1. try RDP Client 7.0 [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21887)
2. Hotfix for RDP 6.1 [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972828)